# How to open an index.html

Tags: redirect, virtualhost, apache2.4

I have a site with two different languages(tr and en). These are in two different folder(tr and en) and each has their own index.html. I want to open tr's index.html at the beginning. My configaration so far;

```
<VirtualHost #ip-address#:80>
    *
    *
    *
    DocumentRoot #path-to-directory#
    *
    *
    *
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to add

```
DirectoryIndex tr/index.html
```

it did not work.

I tried

```
DocumentRoot #path-to-directory#/tr
```

but I could not acces

```
http://<site-name>/en/index.html
```

How can I do that? I have tried redirect but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are able to force the browser to show the default page, as that sort of defeats it's purpose. The best idea I could think of would be to leave the default as index.html, and use mod_rewrite to direct index.html to app.php.

This should work for the default index ( [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com/)) and show desired url in browser ( [www.domain.com/app.php](http://www.domain.com/app.php) )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *.mysite.co.uk
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mysite/web/"
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ app.php$1 [L,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Actually, I want to redirect www.domain.com to www.domain.com/tr/index.html to acces index.html under "/var/www/html/mysite/web/tr" but also another index.html file under "/var/www/html/mysite/web/en" and when language changes these index.htmls are used.

Comment: RedirectMatch is the answer for me. Thanks for attention :)

Comment: Found it. . . there was another DirectoryIndex directive buried in the conf file, that was set to index.php. Apparently a directive specified in a virtual host does not overwrite directives specified in the 'main configuration'.